# App slow ONLY on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm debuggin my app on several device, including an Oppo Find 7a (Android 6.0.1, Snapdragon 801 and 2GB of RAM), a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini(Android 5.1, Exynos something and 1.5GB of RAM), an old Samsung tablet (Android IV.IV.I, Hamster on a wheel, 3 candy) as well as a just bought Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (Android 6.0.1, Exynos something, 4GB of RAM).

The main comparison I made where between the new S7 and the Oppo, because i thought having the same Android version they could have been see as the same devive with an HW upgrade.

Therefore, I have HUGE performance issues on the NEW Samsung S7. Not only comparing it with the Oppo, but also with the older models. Even the Tablet can easily make the S7 eat the dust.

MoreOver, I'm reporting crashes on the S7 with the common OutOfMemoryExeption, even if his threshold is 256MB (2x the S5 Mini in which the app runs smoothly in every condition)

I make large use of HTTP request using Volley, as well as dynamic content with fragments and viewPagers.

Here's the log of the last run of the app http://pastebin.com/EwuKZKLa

Could you please help me finding out why only on this device I have these problems? (The device is 100% original if you are guessing)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to your stack trace, a placeholder drawable resource that Glide is trying to use is much too large. Android needs to allocate 132,710,412 bytes for this image. That is the equivalent of a 5738px by 5738px image, which is larger than the device screen.

My guess is that you have this drawable in `res/drawable/`. That is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. That image is then being up-sampled to the `-xxxhdpi` (or whatever the density is of the S7 Edge), and that is where your problem lies. Create proper density renditions of this image, or move it into `res/drawable-nodpi/` or `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

With regards to your "HUGE performance issues", use method tracing and similar tools to determine exactly where your problem lies.

Comment: Thanks, for a quick control i temporary enabled the largeHeap, and the exception disappeared. I'll now look into the resource file to see if I found anything.

Comment: Thanks so much @CommonWare you saved our day! We wouldn't ever consider the placeholder as a possible issue, it's a png of 12kb...

Comment: This is a very valuable answer/information about performance with drawable png/jpeg resources. I feel the pain of a high-end device dying slowing because the png files from res/drawable are up-sampled in every layout renderization. As a curiosity, this is really worse in Samsung hig-end devices compared to other low-end devices.